# iOS6 app state save and restoration

Tags: iphone, ios6, save, state

My app's minimum support iOS version is iOS5. And I didn't do any state save and restoration.
    It works well on my self iphone4, but some users complain the app is reset when they pick up a phone call or change to other app and back.
    So, I take state restoration more serious, and I want to add it into my app.
    However, I have image album function, so I call ALAssetLibrary.
I need to create the exact the same thumbnail view as it was.
I have some background Operations in operationQueue, so I need to know their state and add the unfinished background operations. It's a little complicated.
   Here're my questions.
   1. I didn't find useful sample code, project. (session208 in WWDC2012, but they didn't release code in WWDC sample code release), Do you know any?
   2. what's the best way to do it ? follow iOS6 or make it by myself?
      what's the difference.
   3. For ALAssetlibrary, image thumbnail viewing, how could I achieve state save and restoration?

Answer (score 2):

Definitely use Apple's APIs, don't reinvent the wheel. The [WWDC 2012 session about this](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=208) used the WWDC 2012 app as the example to show off the feature, there was never any demo project to share to developers. However they have since (recently) released a demo to demonstrate it, you can find it here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/StateRestore/Introduction/Intro.html

It sounds like your state is complex, and I'm not sure you really want to be restoring those background operations. You probably will find it better to restore the user to a more stable part of your app.

For your ALAssetlibrary question, you would save an ID to the current image in your `encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:` implementation of your view controller, make sure you read up on the documentation, you'll need to conform to a protocol, set a restoration class if you're in code or using xibs (not using storyboard)... you would save the ID doing something like this:

```
NSString * const ImageReferenceIDKey = @"ImageReferenceID";

- (void)encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    NSString *objectID = nil; // get some ID that can relocate your image
    [coder encodeObject:objectID forKey:ImageReferenceIDKey];
    [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];
}

- (void)decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    [super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];
    NSString *objectID = [coder objectForKey:ImageReferenceIDKey];
    // get into the ALAssetlibrary and use the objectID to restore which image you had.
}
```

Notice I call `super` last in the encode method, but first in the decode method.

You should be very careful about the user having changed the privacy of your access to their photos, don't crash on them, if you try to restore a photo make sure you still have permissions to do so, or you might crash.